# Are "Web Fonts" actual redesigns for screen display or

Tags: fonts, font-face, eot

Are the recent plethora of "Web Fonts" available for use with @font-face actual redesigns of original fonts for enhanced screen display or are they just conversions to .eot format, in which case they may look awful at normal body text size ?

N.B. I'm thinking of the official font versions available from Linotype and Adobe etc.

Comment: Consider rephrasing this question. It is too general and is impossible to answer definitively. Some web fonts made by some companies may be simple conversions. Some may be re-worked. Some designs, even if redesigned, will never look good at normal body text sizes because they were originally intended for headlines or titling. It is highly dependent upon the specific font you are interested in and where you get it from.

Comment: I think you answered my question or at least your views are the same as mine. The vast majority of web fonts from the leading font foundries are designed for print and no amount of re-working will ever make them optimal for web usage except for Titling at a larger point sizes than body text size. So I fail to see the point of using them unless a lot of largish titling is taking place.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure how you are reaching that conclusion from my comment. I don't think my views are the same. My view is that it is highly dependent on the font and the vendor. Some vendors have released webfonts that have been specifically tuned for screen use and at text sizes. Some haven't. It really depends on what you're looking for and who you're dealing with.

Comment: So how do you dertimine if a font is specifically a screen font as opposed to a converted to eot type without regard for screen display quality. IS there some "type" or "identifier" that I should be looking for ?

Comment: Unfortunately, probably not. But, most vendors have some sort of preview option that should help you decide whether the font you're interested is going to be suitable for use as a text/body font or otherwise. WebType.com puts guidelines for "intended use" with each font, which may help a bit.